# $formatters and $parsers not called in AngularJS 1.6.2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.6

> @version angularjs 1.6.2

I'm trying to do some formatters and parsers to have generic input/output for my really huge project.

The use case :

I have a custom component with ngModelController required on it, but when I use this component in my view with an attribute directive; which also requires ngModel to add $parser or $formatters; but when the value is changing into the component the $formatters or $parsers assign on it aren't called.

Te logic I would like

Component : ArtistSelect
Directive (parser) : ngObject ng-object-formatter="attribute_object" ng-object-parser="attribute_object"
View :

```
<artist-select ng-model="model.artist" ng-object ng-object-formatter="id_artist"></artist-select>
```

I would like the model.artist being formatted like : {id_artist: integer} instead of only an integer.

> **Angular doc :** Note that the $parsers are not called when the bound
>   ngModel expression changes programmatically.

also

> **Angular Doc** : Since ng-model does not do a deep watch, $render() is only invoked if
>   the values of $modelValue and $viewValue are actually different from
>   their previous values. If $modelValue or $viewValue are objects
>   (rather than a string or number) then $render() will not be invoked if
>   you only change a property on the objects.

How to make it work ?

**WORKING PLUNKER :**  [Behavior](https://plnkr.co/edit/9yPQ2SN0OpCEJ301OmKc)

Maybe I'm missing something, maybe I'm overthinking the the things or maybe It's just not possible to do.

Your help will be really appreciated !

Comment: The implementation and a simple demo would be useful. At the moment, it's quite impossible to say where the problem is.

Comment: Adding a plunkr

Comment: Plunker added have some issue implementing ui-select into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was in my $doCheck(), I made a check which was never true.